# android studio Error:(20, 0) Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'android()'!

Tags: gradle

Error:(20, 0) Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'android()'!

Possible causes could be:
  - you are using Gradle version where the method is absent (Fix Gradle settings)
  - you didn't apply Gradle plugin which provides the method (Apply Gradle plugin)
  - or there is a mistake in a build script (Goto source)

this is the android studio error message!I'd clicked "Fix gradle settings" check the default option.but not resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that the `build.gradle` for which the error occurs is missing a line such as `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` at the top. (Details depend on which version of the Android Gradle plugin your build is using.)